# Jquery animate right page width issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I've created a button that floats on the right page.

On selection, I've made div.enquiry-box animate to the left.  Selecting close will animate to the right.

I've made the appropriate jfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/6j0mptsp/

The issue I have, is when the div is to right of the button (awaiting the click of btn-make to make it slide into place).  The div indeed sits to the right but the page width increases and can be scrolled to see the enquiry-box sitting there.

What's the best way to get around this?
html

```
    <div class="slide-box">
    <a href="#" class="btn-make">
        <img src="images/btn-side-newsletter.png" alt="Newsletter signup" /></a>
    <div class="enquiry-box show">
        <h2>Receive Newsletter</h2>
        <p>Enter your email address below to receive the Wesport Newsletter</p>
        <div class="row">
            <input id="side-email" name="side-email" class="side-email" />
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/btn-side-send.png" alt="send" /></a>
            <a class="slide-close" href="#"><img src="images/btn-flyout-close.png" alt="close" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".btn-make").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if ($(".enquiry-box").hasClass('show')) {
                $(".enquiry-box").animate({
                    right: "+39"
                }, 700, function() {
                    // Animation complete.
                });
            }
            $(".enquiry-box").removeClass('show')
        });
        $(".slide-close").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

                $(".enquiry-box").animate({
                right: "-252"
                }, 700, function() {
                    // Animation complete.
                });

            $(".enquiry-box").addClass('show')
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing from the css

```
body
{
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

d'oh